# Lumber thickness

Tags: lumber

[image]I want to build Shoji screen door and need to set a frame from lumber pine to hold the door.
Door width 5.5 meters(18 feet), height 2.5 meters (8.1 feet)
Between the left and right lumbers(blue ones) is a wall(concrete), above the upper lumber(Yellow) is air (the height of the room is 3.75 meters), the upper only supported by the left and right lumbers(blue ones).
I do have 6 meters long lumbers with 10x10cm or 15x15cm or 20x20cm or 25x25cm.
It's inside the house(above the yellow air, above the air roof, no snow :)), the only purpose of this construction is to hold the Shoji screen sliding doors.
The lumber is pieces of glued pine.
So, what is the lumber thinkness should I use? 10, 15, 20, 25 cm?
Thank u all, and sorry for lake of explanation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. If you're essentially just building a doorframe I don't think you need to go beyond what the dimensions that are commonly used for that purpose in your home. If the requirement is a little more specific than that you'll need to provide more detail. In case you don't realise, buying stuff in the needed lengths could pose some difficulty! 2.5m should be no problem, but if you intend to span the full 5.5m without joints that may require a special order, and could work out very expensive.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by a "frame"? If what you are referring to is a structural frame to support the wall above, then we would need more information regarding the building construction.  Even then we might defer with a recommendation that a structural engineer guide you.  If you are referring to the facing face trim in the opening, then standard thickness boards should work.  Could you add a sketch of what you are planning to do and what you need sized?

Comment: Assume you are asking a colleague who knows nothing about what "Shoji" is, but you want their advice on carpentry. [Edit] the question to tell us briefly what it is you want to do and what part of your plan you need assistance with. A quick sketch can help you, and us, understand what it is you are doing.

Comment: This question might be more at home at [diy.stackexchange.com](https://diy.stackexchange.com). Have you looked there for similar questions and answers?

Comment: When you edit the question, please describe the exact dimensions of the panels.

Comment: when you say 'air' above the yellow beam, is it really open to the sky?  or is there a roof on it?  If it's open to the sky, any size will do, if there is any load on it (including the roof) it needs a big header.  As an example, an 18' wide garage door needs 3 x 2"x16" to span that distance

Comment: @bowlturner, I take the update to mean there's a 3.75m ceiling.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, they make your requirement *much* clearer. We could probably do with knowing the last dimension on the wood you have.... I presume you've listed the width? Are they all the same thickness or does it go up as the width increases? I did some rough calculations and given the total span is unsupported/unattached I suspect you'll want to use your widest material, *or possibly even glue up two (maybe even three) of the 10cm boards to maximise stiffness* — because even minimal sag (<1cm) in the centre could be enough to prevent the shoji from sliding.

Comment: @Graphus, his tallest boards are 25cm, an 18ft span needs a header at least 5 1/4" x 16" , he'd need 6 20cm boards to get the width and height required if it's load bearing.  If they have a lot of snow it might need to be bigger yet!

Comment: The added information does raise a few more questions.  Are you removing a concrete wall to create this opening? Does the header (yellow part) you are trying to size support any other weight besides itself and the shoji screens?  If the header only supports the shoji assembly then we can answer the size question.  If anything more, this becomes a structural question that is beyond the scope of this site.  Please clarify what the loads on the header will be.

Comment: @bowlturner, are you saying a no-load header to span a 16.4' gap would need to be 5 1/4" (!) thick and 16" wide???

Comment: @Ashlar, unless I've completely misunderstood this the header/beam supports nothing but its own weight. Obviously the picture changes completely if the shoji are intended to *hang* from it, something I hadn't considered at all :-o If the screens will just slide in a channel as I'd assumed it 'only' needs to span the gap between the two uprights (which I nominally picked as 25mm wide to visually match the header, making the span 5m or 16.4').

Comment: @Graphus no.  one with a load, would need that, without a load it just needs to be strong enough to hold the doors/screens.

Comment: @Graphus u are correct, it's support only the Shoji sliding door

Comment: Sounds like this is a frame whose only job is to support the sliding Shoji doors. It will be [attached to/leaning against] the concrete wall behind it, hiding the wall and adding decoration. Will these doors actually be able to slide to expose the wall behind them, or will they be fixed in position? If they have to slide, the header has to be sturdier to support the sliding hardware and the moving doors. If they're fixed, the doors can help support the header.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not a load bearing opening, and all it needs to do is hold the doors up a much smaller header would be required.  it is still a long gap to span and the doors will have some weight.  the 15x15 would probably do fine, but I would recommend bumping it up to the 20x20, and going with the 25x25 you certainly wouldn't be unhappy with that.

To recap, I think the 15x15 might just pass muster, at least for a little while but since you have bigger options ready, I would go with one of them.